# Google protobuf implementation with 'C' compiler

Tags: protocol-buffers, iar

I am planning for CoAP protocol implementation on my target (NXP Kinetis K65 with IAR compiler). I want to use "Google Protobuf (protocol buffers)" for data encoding.

However I am not sure, how I can set up IAR compiler to work with these .proto files? 
or
I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: What have you tried, and what didn't work? There are [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) for how to get started with protocol buffers, including writing/generating/using in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the IDE, if you are using the stand alone compiler it should not differ from any other system, you add makefile rules to generate c++-files from the .proto-files.

To do the same in EWARM you need to register protoc as an external tool that converts .proto-files to c++ source files. To do this, open the project options and select the "Custom Build" category and fill in the dialog.

[image: Custom tool configuration for protoc]

Now you should be able to add the .proto-files to the project and they will be built when you build the project. For more information read about "adding an external tool" in the EWARM IDE-guide.